# Dictionary type property does not show up in property grid

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

In my custom activity i have property of type Dictionary< String , Argument > I have set up custom editor for this property using MetadataStore. The problem is that property does not show up in property grid.

If i change type of the property from Dictionary< string,Argument> to for example Collection< KeyValuePair< string,Argument>> property does show up in property grid. But i cannot use Collection variant because i want to use DynamicArgumentDesignerOptions for ModelItemDictionary edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was adding

```
[Browsable(true)]
```

to the Dictionary property.